# How to write a stream that requires the consumer to memcpy the contents of a slice into its own allocation?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I would like to implement a futures [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) that yields collections of `f32`s. My code looks something like this:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c213336ddaf1e52146c85f26591e5ad8

Inside the `poll_next` method on line 49 there is a potential heap allocation of a Vec which is currently necessary in order to pass ownership of the data to the consumer. I would like the iterator to be usable in real-time contexts, so I would like to avoid this.

One option seems to be to allocate a local Vec owned by the Iterator, and copy incoming data into it. Ideally, the consumer should be somehow required to memcpy the available contents of this local Vec into its own pre-allocated memory on each iteration.

However, changing to `Item = &[f32]` results in the following error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:36:17
   |
36 |     type Item = &[f32];
   |                 ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
36 |     type Item<'a> = &'a [f32];
   |              ^^^^   ^^^
```

Are explicit lifetimes a valid solution here? If not how can I avoid the heap allocation inside the iterator?

Comment: I believe it's would be quite hard without knowing `get_f32s` signature. Or even maybe you should consider another approach (e.g. do a batching at consumer-side).

Comment: If you don't want to allocate a new vector for each slice then the `Stream::Item` cannot be `Vec`.

Comment: This is not easy. But most of the work needs to be done in the ring buffer. It's hard to answer without that code.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, question updated. Hope it's clearer.